# React-Bootstrap - How to create rows of 4 cards each?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

how do I set the number of cards per row? I need 4 cards to be in one row of mine.
I have been trying for hours.. can't figure out what i do wrong..
I was getting all sorts of errors when i played around with this.
like this one :
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tYPPb.png)

my package.json file:
[image: my package.json file:]

thanks!
:)

```
import { React } from 'react';
import { Card, Button, CardGroup } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';


const MyDishes = props => {
    const { dishes } = props;

    return (
        <CardGroup style={{display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'row'}}>
            {dishes.length > 0 &&
                dishes.map(d => (
                    <Row xs={1} md={2} className="g-4">
                    {Array.from({ length: 4 }).map((_, idx) => (
                    <Col>
     
                    <Card key={d.id} style={{ width: '100em' }} style={{flex: 1}}>
                        <Card.Img variant="top" src={d.attributes.picture} />
                        <Card.Body>
                            <Card.Title>{d.attributes.name}</Card.Title>
                            <Card.Text>Possibly some text here</Card.Text>
                            <Link to={`/dishes/${d.id}`}>
                                <Button variant="primary">Full Recipe</Button>
                            </Link>
                        </Card.Body>
                    </Card>
                    </Col>
                ))}
                </Row>
        </CardGroup>
    );
};

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        dishes: state.myDishes
    };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(MyDishes);
```

i get this error now :
[image: new error]

Comment: I'm working on it

Comment: ok thanks! will be waiting for your response

Comment: Please add `package.json` of your project @DevA

Comment: ok just uploaded a screenshot of it

Comment: check the answer @DevA

Answer (score 0):

1. To use bootstrap layout system, must use `<Container>` to wrap `<Row>` and `<Col>`
2. You don't need custom styles to achieve that you want.

```
import { React } from 'react';
import { Container, Card, Button, CardGroup } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';


const MyDishes = props => {
    const { dishes } = props;

    return (
        <Container>
            {dishes.length > 0 &&
                dishes.map(d => (
                    <Row xs={1} md={2} className="g-4">
                    {Array.from({ length: 4 }).map((_, idx) => (
                    <Col>
                    <Card key={d.id}>
                        <Card.Img variant="top" src={d.attributes.picture} />
                        <Card.Body>
                            <Card.Title>{d.attributes.name}</Card.Title>
                            <Card.Text>Possibly some text here</Card.Text>
                            <Link to={`/dishes/${d.id}`}>
                                <Button variant="primary">Full Recipe</Button>
                            </Link>
                        </Card.Body>
                    </Card>
                    </Col>
                ))}
                </Row>
              ))}
        </Container>
    );
};

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        dishes: state.myDishes
    };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(MyDishes);
```

Comment: i got an error.. i attached it under your edited code

Comment: still erroring :/

Comment: @DevA does answer help?

Comment: it shows the same dish card 4 times.. (for each dish)

Comment: Add `dishes` json to solve this

Comment: What do you mean? Sorry I’m a beginner

Comment: Ok. No problem.  In the component you get `dishes` as props. Where did it come?

Comment: oh I am not sure :/ i followed the steps from my course video.. wanna try to help me on a different question ?  i also got this one : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69270460/constructor-question-react-javascript-for-incrementing