# React Bootstrap - Adding logic to a button

Tags: reactjs, ruby-on-rails, react-bootstrap

I am trying to add logic to my Project's button - this is the logic :

```
<Button>
<input variant="primary" type="submit" value={editMode ? "Update Recipe" : "Create Recipe" }>

</input>
</Button>
```

So far I couldn't find a way to implement it.. so I ended up with an input inside of my button - which. looks very much weird.
Could someone give me an insight?

[here is what it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HVVj6.png)
Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [this documentation](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/forms/?), to implement a submit button in a form you can try this:

```
<Button variant="primary" type="submit">
    {editMode ? "Update Recipe" : "Create Recipe" }
</Button>
```

Instead of putting an input field inside of a button, you can actually use the button as an input instead.

Comment: If you want you could try this too :  :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69238417/react-bootstrap-how-to-create-rows-of-4-cards-each